# Xcode 9.0 segmentation fault 11 while type-checking Codable in Swift

Tags: swift, segmentation-fault

Xcode 9.0 gives me this error while trying to compile a struct:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

```
struct DataModel: Codable {
  struct Head : Codable {}

  struct Text : Codable {
    let text: String
  }

  struct Tr : Codable {
    let text: String
    let pos: String
    let syn: [Text]!
    let mean: [Text]!
    let ex: [AltTranslation]!
  }

  struct AltTranslation: Codable{
    let text: String
    let tr: [Text]!
  }

  struct def: Codable{
    let text: String
    let pos: String
    let tr: [Tr]!
  }

  let head: Head
  let def: [def]!
}
```

The only change I made in this file since the last successful compilation is changing the names of sub-structs.

Comment: And when I change names back everything compiles.

Comment: The compiler should never crash though... you should [file a bug](https://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: I already did @Hamish

Comment: I don't see it on bugs.swift.org, did you post it there or with Apple instead? For Swift bugs, the former is usually preferable.

Comment: I've posted it on Apple, will also post on Swift now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a struct and a constant named `def`. Rename one to avoid ambiguity.